# iOS: how can I implement a color picker into my app?

Tags: ios

How can I implement a color picker for my app like this: http://cl.ly/8pqv
 into my application?

And possibly compatible with iOS 3.0?

Or are there any librarie? I need the wheel with all colors..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually have a class called `ANColorPicker`.  It provides a wheel interface with a brightness selector on the side.  You can check it out on the [ANColorPicker Github Repository](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANColorPicker).  There are also a few [forks](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANColorPicker/network) of this project that have different features/capabilities in which you may be interested.

Comment: There is only one thing I don't understand: why do I need to drag a little bit my finger on the color picker in order to select a color ? I mean, if I just tap it, I can't select it.

Comment: You will have to call touchesMoved: from the touchesBegan method in order to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [this method](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/). Basically, you would create your own image of a color wheel, then when the user touches part of the image, you find the color of the pixel at the touch point and make that the currently selected color. Otherwise, if you don't have to have a circular color picker, here is an [example of a square color picker with source code](http://www.fabiancanas.com/entry/iphone-color-picker).

Comment: @WTP actually not all apps are for people with visual disabilities, for example my app is about visual art!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would throw my color picker into the ring. I use it in my app, [You Doodle](http://bit.ly/YouDoodleApp) and I spent a couple weeks making it and testing it in the app. It contains a sample project to show you how to get started with it and is open sourced under the MIT license. It supports any device (iOS 6+), any resolution and portrait and landscape. Favorites, recents, color by hue, color wheel and importing textures, as well as deleting and moving favorites to the front is supported.

I've tried to combine the good pieces of all the other color pickers and ensure that the MIT license allows a no hassle integration into any project.

**Github:** https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker

**Screenshots:**

[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]
[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]
[image: DRColorPicker iPhone]
[image: DRColorPicker iPad]