# Simple swift color picker popover (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, popover, color-picker, color-palette

Is there is a simple way to implement a color picker popover in swift?  Are there any built-in libraries or UI elements that I could leverage for this purpose?  I saw some color pickers written in objective-c, but they were several years old and I was wondering if there was something more recent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With iOS 14 Apple has now implemented a standard [UIColorPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorpickerviewcontroller) and associated [UIColorWell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorwell) that is a color swatch that automatically brings up the UIColorPicker to choose a color.

You can test the ColorPicker by creating a Swift App project with Xcode 12 or later, targeting iOS 14+ and then try this simple code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var bgColor = Color.white

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ColorPicker("Set the background color",
                        selection: $bgColor,
                        supportsOpacity: true)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(bgColor)
    }
}
```

Change `supportsOpacity` to `false` to get rid of the opacity slider and only allow fully opaque colors.

ColorPicker showing two different modes of selection:

[image: iOS 14 ColorPicker]

ColorPicker without alpha:

[image: iOS ColorPicker no alpha]

Comment: How can I use it with regular Swift in a UIViewController class?

Answer (score 97):

Here's one I made which is as simple as it gets. It's just a lightweight UIView that allows you to specify the element size in case you want blocked regions (elementSize > 1). It draws itself in interface builder so you can set element size and see the consequences. Just set one of your views in interface builder to this class and then set yourself as a delegate. It will tell you when someone either taps or drags on it and the uicolor at that location. It will draw itself to its own bounds and there's no need for anything other than this class, no image required.

**Element size=1 (Default)**
[image: element size=1]

**Element size=10**
[image: element size=10]

```
internal protocol HSBColorPickerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func HSBColorColorPickerTouched(sender:HSBColorPicker, color:UIColor, point:CGPoint, state:UIGestureRecognizerState)
}

@IBDesignable
class HSBColorPicker : UIView {

    weak internal var delegate: HSBColorPickerDelegate?
    let saturationExponentTop:Float = 2.0
    let saturationExponentBottom:Float = 1.3

    @IBInspectable var elementSize: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    private func initialize() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        let touchGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touchedColor(gestureRecognizer:)))
        touchGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        touchGesture.allowableMovement = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        self.addGestureRecognizer(touchGesture)
    }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        for y : CGFloat in stride(from: 0.0 ,to: rect.height, by: elementSize) {
            var saturation = y < rect.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * y) / rect.height : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect.height - y) / rect.height
            saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), y < rect.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
            let brightness = y < rect.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect.height - y) / rect.height
            for x : CGFloat in stride(from: 0.0 ,to: rect.width, by: elementSize) {
                let hue = x / rect.width
                let color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
                context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
                context!.fill(CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:elementSize,height:elementSize))
            }
        }
    }

    func getColorAtPoint(point:CGPoint) -> UIColor {
        let roundedPoint = CGPoint(x:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.x / elementSize)),
                               y:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.y / elementSize)))
        var saturation = roundedPoint.y < self.bounds.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * roundedPoint.y) / self.bounds.height
        : 2.0 * CGFloat(self.bounds.height - roundedPoint.y) / self.bounds.height
        saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), roundedPoint.y < self.bounds.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
        let brightness = roundedPoint.y < self.bounds.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(self.bounds.height - roundedPoint.y) / self.bounds.height
        let hue = roundedPoint.x / self.bounds.width
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func getPointForColor(color:UIColor) -> CGPoint {
        var hue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var saturation: CGFloat = 0.0
        var brightness: CGFloat = 0.0
        color.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: nil);

        var yPos:CGFloat = 0
        let halfHeight = (self.bounds.height / 2)
        if (brightness >= 0.99) {
            let percentageY = powf(Float(saturation), 1.0 / saturationExponentTop)
            yPos = CGFloat(percentageY) * halfHeight
        } else {
            //use brightness to get Y
            yPos = halfHeight + halfHeight * (1.0 - brightness)
        }
        let xPos = hue * self.bounds.width
        return CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
    }

    @objc func touchedColor(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
            let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
            let color = getColorAtPoint(point: point)
            self.delegate?.HSBColorColorPickerTouched(sender: self, color: color, point: point, state:gestureRecognizer.state)
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that you placed the code right here in Stack Overflow rather than linking to some github project.

Comment: One thing that is missing here is a gray scale.

Comment: Looks beautiful, but I haven't been able to adapt it to my existing Objective C project. In fact, I get errors on the swift file which has the above code. I've imported UIKit, but to me it looks like Swift's changed its grammar? Is the code above compatible with Swift 2.3? I use Xcode 8.1. My apology if I'm not making sense as I'm new to Swift. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: When I get back to this, I'll add greyscale as well. We use swift 3.0 now, but if anyone wants to supply their translated code I'll update it.

Comment: Figured that the color return wrong because longPressGesture get called twice with wrong calculation, updated the code a bit

Comment: Thanks for this nice piece of code. I had some problems with the getPointForColor when called from viewDidLoad : the returned point was not positioned at the right location into the color view. It happens that we should rather call it from viewDidLayoutSubviews, once all auto layout resizing operations done.

Comment: For some reason I get nil for context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext().  Not sure why I am not getting a context.  When is the right time to call the draw method? I am using the Swift 3 version below BUT with Swift 4.

Comment: This is great and works perfectly in Swift 4.2. Though how exactly do you use the color value? It comes up as an UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace. Is there any way to convert this to a UIColor?

Answer (score 14):

Based on Joel Teply code (Swift 4), with gray bar on top:

```
import UIKit


class ColorPickerView : UIView {

var onColorDidChange: ((_ color: UIColor) -> ())?

let saturationExponentTop:Float = 2.0
let saturationExponentBottom:Float = 1.3

let grayPaletteHeightFactor: CGFloat = 0.1
var rect_grayPalette = CGRect.zero
var rect_mainPalette = CGRect.zero

// adjustable
var elementSize: CGFloat = 1.0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

private func setup() {

    self.clipsToBounds = true
    let touchGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touchedColor(gestureRecognizer:)))
    touchGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    touchGesture.allowableMovement = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    self.addGestureRecognizer(touchGesture)
}



override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    rect_grayPalette = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height * grayPaletteHeightFactor)
    rect_mainPalette = CGRect(x: 0, y: rect_grayPalette.maxY,
                              width: rect.width, height: rect.height - rect_grayPalette.height)

    // gray palette
    for y in stride(from: CGFloat(0), to: rect_grayPalette.height, by: elementSize) {

        for x in stride(from: (0 as CGFloat), to: rect_grayPalette.width, by: elementSize) {
            let hue = x / rect_grayPalette.width

            let color = UIColor(white: hue, alpha: 1.0)

            context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context!.fill(CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:elementSize, height:elementSize))
        }
    }

    // main palette
    for y in stride(from: CGFloat(0), to: rect_mainPalette.height, by: elementSize) {

        var saturation = y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * y) / rect_mainPalette.height : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - y) / rect_mainPalette.height
        saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
        let brightness = y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - y) / rect_mainPalette.height

        for x in stride(from: (0 as CGFloat), to: rect_mainPalette.width, by: elementSize) {
            let hue = x / rect_mainPalette.width

            let color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)

            context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context!.fill(CGRect(x:x, y: y + rect_mainPalette.origin.y,
                                 width: elementSize, height: elementSize))
        }
    }
}



func getColorAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIColor
{
    var roundedPoint = CGPoint(x:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.x / elementSize)),
                               y:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.y / elementSize)))

    let hue = roundedPoint.x / self.bounds.width


    // main palette
    if rect_mainPalette.contains(point)
    {
        // offset point, because rect_mainPalette.origin.y is not 0
        roundedPoint.y -= rect_mainPalette.origin.y

        var saturation = roundedPoint.y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * roundedPoint.y) / rect_mainPalette.height
            : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - roundedPoint.y) / rect_mainPalette.height

        saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), roundedPoint.y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
        let brightness = roundedPoint.y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - roundedPoint.y) / rect_mainPalette.height

        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    // gray palette
    else{

        return UIColor(white: hue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}


@objc func touchedColor(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    let color = getColorAtPoint(point: point)

    self.onColorDidChange?(color)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
    let colorPickerView = ColorPickerView()
    colorPickerView.onColorDidChange = { [weak self] color in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // use picked color for your needs here...
            self?.view.backgroundColor = color
        }

    }

    // add it to some view and set constraints
    ...
```

Comment: can you please explain on how to use the code in a VC? or post an example on how it is done?

Comment: updated my answer. Got rid of delegate for simplicity.

Comment: MichaelRos, I tried your code the following way but nothing happened when I click on the button. What did I do wrong?                                      class CustomizationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func backgroundColorSelector(_ sender: Any) {

        let colorPickerView = ColorPickerView()
        colorPickerView.onColorDidChange = { [weak self] color in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.view.backgroundColor = color
            }

        }

    }
}

Comment: Got it working by adding an UIView and assigned to ColorPickerView class. Thank you.

Comment: @Yan I also added UIView on Top of view controller and I not getting nothing

Comment: You can wrap it in a UIViewController like this: `class ColorPickerController: UIViewController { var setColor: ((UIColor) -> Void)?; init() { super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) }; required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }; override func loadView() { let colorPickerView = ColorPickerView(); colorPickerView.onColorDidChange = setColor; view = colorPickerView } }` (replace the `;` with new lines)

Answer (score 13):

Swift 3.0 version of [@joel-teply](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060382/joel-teply)'s answer:

```
internal protocol HSBColorPickerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func HSBColorColorPickerTouched(sender:HSBColorPicker, color:UIColor, point:CGPoint, state:UIGestureRecognizerState)
}

@IBDesignable
class HSBColorPicker : UIView {

    weak internal var delegate: HSBColorPickerDelegate?
    let saturationExponentTop:Float = 2.0
    let saturationExponentBottom:Float = 1.3

    @IBInspectable var elementSize: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }


    private func initialize() {

        self.clipsToBounds = true
        let touchGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touchedColor(gestureRecognizer:)))
        touchGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        touchGesture.allowableMovement = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        self.addGestureRecognizer(touchGesture)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        for y in stride(from: (0 as CGFloat), to: rect.height, by: elementSize) {

            var saturation = y < rect.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * y) / rect.height : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect.height - y) / rect.height
            saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), y < rect.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
            let brightness = y < rect.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect.height - y) / rect.height

            for x in stride(from: (0 as CGFloat), to: rect.width, by: elementSize) {
                let hue = x / rect.width
                let color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
                context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
                context!.fill(CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:elementSize,height:elementSize))
            }
        }
    }

    func getColorAtPoint(point:CGPoint) -> UIColor {
        let roundedPoint = CGPoint(x:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.x / elementSize)),
                                   y:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.y / elementSize)))
        var saturation = roundedPoint.y < self.bounds.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * roundedPoint.y) / self.bounds.height
            : 2.0 * CGFloat(self.bounds.height - roundedPoint.y) / self.bounds.height
        saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), roundedPoint.y < self.bounds.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
        let brightness = roundedPoint.y < self.bounds.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(self.bounds.height - roundedPoint.y) / self.bounds.height
        let hue = roundedPoint.x / self.bounds.width
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func getPointForColor(color:UIColor) -> CGPoint {
        var hue:CGFloat=0;
        var saturation:CGFloat=0;
        var brightness:CGFloat=0;
        color.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: nil);

        var yPos:CGFloat = 0
        let halfHeight = (self.bounds.height / 2)

        if (brightness >= 0.99) {
            let percentageY = powf(Float(saturation), 1.0 / saturationExponentTop)
            yPos = CGFloat(percentageY) * halfHeight
        } else {
            //use brightness to get Y
            yPos = halfHeight + halfHeight * (1.0 - brightness)
        }

        let xPos = hue * self.bounds.width

        return CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
    }

    func touchedColor(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
        let color = getColorAtPoint(point: point)

        self.delegate?.HSBColorColorPickerTouched(sender: self, color: color, point: point, state:gestureRecognizer.state)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the starting point.

I took it from there and wrote a complte Color PickerViewController with a custom UIView and some drawing code.

I made the custom UIView @IBDesignable so it can be rendered in InterfaceBuilder.

https://github.com/Christian1313/iOS_Swift_ColorPicker

Answer (score 2):

I quickly added code to implement a color picker for a ViewController using Apples color picker released in IOS 14.   Make sure your deployment info is at least IOS 14.0 or better.  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorpickerviewcontroller for reference.

Add the color picker delegate to the class, and declare a color picker object :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate  {
    
    let colorPicker = UIColorPickerViewController()
```

at the very end of viewDidLoad, I set the colorPicker delegate to self

```
        colorPicker.delegate = self

    } // ends viewDidLoad
```

I use a single color picker to choose colors for several different objects.  When I present the color picker to the user, I set a boolean flag to true to indicate the reason why the color picker is being displayed.

```
        resetAllColorChangeFlags() // First make sure all the booleans are false for robust design

        changingScreenBackgroundColor = true

        present(colorPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I added the APIs to handle colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor and colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish

colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor  checks the boolean flags, and sets a color property for the appropriate object.   If the color is being applied to a border color in a layer, cgColor is used.

```
    func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
        
        if changingScreenBackgroundColor
        {
            self.view.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
        }
        if addingATintCircle
        {
            pointerToThisTintView.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
        }
        if changingTextBackgroundColor
        {
            pointerToTextObjectSelected.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
        }
        if changingTextColor
        {
            pointerToTextObjectSelected.textColor = viewController.selectedColor
        }
        if changingTextBorderColor
        {
            pointerToTextObjectSelected.layer.borderColor = viewController.selectedColor.cgColor
        }
        if changingPhotoBorderColor
        {
            pointerToPhotoObjectSelected.layer.borderColor = viewController.selectedColor.cgColor
        }
        if changingCameraBorderColor {
            cameraView.layer.borderColor = viewController.selectedColor.cgColor
        }
    } // ends colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor
```

colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish  is used just to reset all of my booleans flags that indicate why the color picker has been presented to the user.

```
    func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController)
    {
        resetAllColorChangeFlags()

    } // ends colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish
```

Here is my reset routine :

```
    func resetAllColorChangeFlags()
    {
        changingFunTextColor = false
        changingFunTextFirstColorForGradient = false
        changingFunTextSecondColorForGradient = false
        changingScreenBackgroundColor = false
        changingTextBackgroundColor = false
        changingTextColor = false
        changingTextBorderColor = false
        changingPhotoBorderColor = false
        changingCameraBorderColor = false
        addingATintToAPhotoObject = false
        addingATintCircle = false
        addingAColorForGradients = false
        
    } // ends resetAllColorChangeFlags
```

Comment: Much better if you created an enum and switch

Answer (score 1):

[ColorPickerViewImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaieC.png)

Based on Christian1313 answer, I added **darker colors**:

```
@IBDesignable final public class SwiftColorView: UIView {

weak var colorSelectedDelegate: ColorDelegate?

@IBInspectable public var numColorsX:Int =  10 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

@IBInspectable public var numColorsY:Int = 18 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

@IBInspectable public var coloredBorderWidth:Int = 10 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

@IBInspectable public var showGridLines:Bool = false {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

weak var delegate: SwiftColorPickerDataSource?

public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    colorSelectedDelegate?.setStroke(color: colorAtPoint(point: location))
}

public override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    colorSelectedDelegate?.setStroke(color: colorAtPoint(point: location))
}

public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    let lineColor = UIColor.gray
    let pS = patternSize()
    let w = pS.w
    let h = pS.h

    for y in 0..<numColorsY
    {
        for x in 0..<numColorsX
        {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let start = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x)*w+CGFloat(coloredBorderWidth), y: CGFloat(y)*h+CGFloat(coloredBorderWidth))
            path.move(to: start);
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x+w, y: start.y))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x+w, y: start.y+h))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: start.y+h))
            path.addLine(to: start)
            path.lineWidth = 0.25
            colorForRectAt(x: x,y:y).setFill();

            if (showGridLines)
            {
                lineColor.setStroke()
            }
            else
            {
                colorForRectAt(x: x, y: y).setStroke();
            }
            path.fill();
            path.stroke();
        }
    }
}

private func colorForRectAt(x: Int, y: Int) -> UIColor
{

    if let ds = delegate {
        return ds.colorForPalletIndex(x: x, y: y, numXStripes: numColorsX, numYStripes: numColorsY)
    } else {

        var hue:CGFloat = CGFloat(x) / CGFloat(numColorsX)
        var fillColor = UIColor.white
        if (y==0)
        {
            if (x==(numColorsX-1))
            {
                hue = 1.0;
            }
            fillColor = UIColor(white: hue, alpha: 1.0);
        }
        else
        {
            if y < numColorsY / 2 {
                //dark
                let length = numColorsY / 2
                let brightness: CGFloat = CGFloat(y) / CGFloat(length)
                fillColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
            } else if y == numColorsY / 2 {
                // normal
                fillColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            } else {
                // light
                let length = numColorsY / 2 - 1
                let offset = y - length - 1
                let sat:CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0) - CGFloat(offset) / CGFloat(length + 1)
                print("sat", sat)
                fillColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: sat, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
        return fillColor
    }
}

func colorAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIColor
{
    let pS = patternSize()
    let w = pS.w
    let h = pS.h
    let x = (point.x-CGFloat(coloredBorderWidth))/w
    let y = (point.y-CGFloat(coloredBorderWidth))/h
    return colorForRectAt(x: Int(x), y:Int(y))
}

private func patternSize() -> (w: CGFloat, h:CGFloat)
{
    let width = self.bounds.width-CGFloat(2*coloredBorderWidth)
    let height = self.bounds.height-CGFloat(2*coloredBorderWidth)

    let w = width/CGFloat(numColorsX)
    let h = height/CGFloat(numColorsY)
    return (w,h)
}

public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
{
    print("Compiled and run for IB")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

using Michael Ros answer,

If you want to use this view by objective-c viewcontroller you can simply create a new swift file called ColorPickerView and add a uiview to your viewcontroller on the storyboard and select ColorPickerView as it's class name. then make your view controller a notification observer of name @"colorIsPicked"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateColor) name:@"colorIsPicked" object:nil];
```

Code for ColorPickerView.swift

```
class ColorPickerView : UIView {

@objc public lazy var onColorDidChange: ((_ color: UIColor) -> ()) = {
           
    //send a notification for the caller view to update its elements if necessery
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("colorIsPicked"), object: nil)

}


let saturationExponentTop:Float = 2.0
let saturationExponentBottom:Float = 1.3

let grayPaletteHeightFactor: CGFloat = 0.1
var rect_grayPalette = CGRect.zero
var rect_mainPalette = CGRect.zero

// adjustable
var elementSize: CGFloat = 10.0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    let touchGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touchedColor(gestureRecognizer:)))
    touchGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    touchGesture.allowableMovement = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    self.addGestureRecognizer(touchGesture)
}



override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    
    rect_grayPalette = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height * grayPaletteHeightFactor)
    rect_mainPalette = CGRect(x: 0, y: rect_grayPalette.maxY,
                              width: rect.width, height: rect.height - rect_grayPalette.height)
    
    // gray palette
    for y in stride(from: CGFloat(0), to: rect_grayPalette.height, by: elementSize) {
        
        for x in stride(from: (0 as CGFloat), to: rect_grayPalette.width, by: elementSize) {
            let hue = x / rect_grayPalette.width
            
            let color = UIColor(white: hue, alpha: 1.0)
            
            context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context!.fill(CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:elementSize, height:elementSize))
        }
    }
    
    // main palette
    for y in stride(from: CGFloat(0), to: rect_mainPalette.height, by: elementSize) {
        
        var saturation = y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * y) / rect_mainPalette.height : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - y) / rect_mainPalette.height
        saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
        let brightness = y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - y) / rect_mainPalette.height
        
        for x in stride(from: (0 as CGFloat), to: rect_mainPalette.width, by: elementSize) {
            let hue = x / rect_mainPalette.width
            
            let color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
            
            context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context!.fill(CGRect(x:x, y: y + rect_mainPalette.origin.y,
                                 width: elementSize, height: elementSize))
        }
    }
}



func getColorAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIColor
{
    var roundedPoint = CGPoint(x:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.x / elementSize)),
                               y:elementSize * CGFloat(Int(point.y / elementSize)))
    
    let hue = roundedPoint.x / self.bounds.width
    
    
    // main palette
    if rect_mainPalette.contains(point)
    {
        // offset point, because rect_mainPalette.origin.y is not 0
        roundedPoint.y -= rect_mainPalette.origin.y
        
        var saturation = roundedPoint.y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(2 * roundedPoint.y) / rect_mainPalette.height
            : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - roundedPoint.y) / rect_mainPalette.height
        
        saturation = CGFloat(powf(Float(saturation), roundedPoint.y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? saturationExponentTop : saturationExponentBottom))
        let brightness = roundedPoint.y < rect_mainPalette.height / 2.0 ? CGFloat(1.0) : 2.0 * CGFloat(rect_mainPalette.height - roundedPoint.y) / rect_mainPalette.height
        
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    // gray palette
    else{
        
        return UIColor(white: hue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}


@objc func touchedColor(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    let color = getColorAtPoint(point: point)
    
    self.onColorDidChange(color)
}
 }
```