# Swift - UIView Delegate Protocol not returning value

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, color-picker

I am trying to apply the colour picker from the question below.

[Simple swift color picker popover (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208386/simple-swift-color-picker-popover-ios)

The way I set this up was the colour picker class is attached to a UIView within the main view controller. The code by Michael Ros works but when I try to access it using my main view controller nothing happens. Below is the code I use in my view controller. Is this correct? I went over other questions and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  weak var colorPickerDelegate: ColorPickerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.colorPickerDelegate = self
    } 
  }
}

extension ViewController: colorPickerDelegate {
func colorChanged(color: UIColor) {
   print(color)
  }
}
```

The color picker code can be found on the attached question as I wasn't sure if it was allowed to copy the code over.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sublcass UIView and assign it to the view controllers view, then set the delegate of the ColorPickerView to the view controller:

**ColorPickerView.swift**

```
class ColorPickerView : UIView {

weak var delegate: ColorPickerDelegate?
// Other code from Michael Ros's adaptation.
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var colorPickerView = ColorPickerView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        self.colorPickerView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(colorPickerView)

    }


}

extension ViewController: ColorPickerDelegate {
    func colorDidChange(color: UIColor) {
        print(color)
    }
}
```

[image: View Hierarchy and Debug output]

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

`colorChanged -> colorDidChange  !`

if you delegate is ColorPickerDelegate; I think so

Comment: sorry that was a typo