# Eyedropper tool for iOS?

Tags: swift, uikit, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

Is there a way of accessing just the eyedropper tool in UIColorPickerViewController i.e. assigning it to a button to activate it? It seems like the only way is to bring up the whole modal ColorPicker and then activate it through there. I've scoured Github and there doesn't seem to be any open-source eyedroppers and I don't know where to begin making my own. Total noob so not sure if there's some obvious workaround that I'm missing. Or does iOS limit this sort of functionality in some way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple swift color picker popover (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208386/simple-swift-color-picker-popover-ios)